# Why is EF saying my model has changed when it has not?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I keep getting the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The model backing the 'McContext'
>   context has changed since the database was created. Consider using
>   Code First Migrations to update the database
>   (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

I am creating an .NET MVC 5 website using the latest Entity Framework from nuget, v6.1.3. I am attached to a local MDF file as I don't have SQL Server or Express installed locally. I am using the Code First model.

I spent hours yesterday and today combing through SO and WWW posts on this error, but have not found a solution that works. Most of them revolve around different types of Initializers, or short explanations about how code first requires migrations or initializers for model changes. But I am running the setup manually through the PM console. I have included my steps below.

Connection String:

```
<add name="testSQLConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\jwatts\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MyProject\Databases\MyProject01.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The model:

```
public class Family
{
    public Family() { }

    [Key, Index(IsUnique = true)]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1024)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Changed { get; set; }

    public string ChangedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Deleted { get; set; }

    public string DeletedBy { get; set; }
}
```

The Context:

```
public class McContext : DbContext
{
    public McContext() : base("testSQLConnection") { }

    public DbSet<Family> Families { get; set; }
}
```

The configuration:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Data.McContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        MigrationsDirectory = @"Data\Migrations";
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(McContext context)
    {
        context.Families.Add(new Family()
        {
            Name = "My Family",
            Description = "The family",
            Created = DateTime.Now,
            CreatedBy = "system"
        });
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Auto generated migration class:

```
public partial class StartupConfig : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Families",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    Description = c.String(maxLength: 1024),
                    Created = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    CreatedBy = c.String(),
                    Changed = c.DateTime(),
                    ChangedBy = c.String(),
                    Deleted = c.DateTime(),
                    DeletedBy = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .Index(t => t.Id, unique: true);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropIndex("dbo.Families", new[] { "Id" });
        DropTable("dbo.Families");
    }
}
```

Unit test code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CreateTheContext_Test()
{
    using (var ctx = new McContext())
    {
        //error on this line below:
        var fam = ctx.Families.Where(f => f.Name.Contains("My")).FirstOrDefault();
        Assert.IsTrue(fam != null && fam.Name.Contains("My"));
    }   
}
```

Recreation steps:

1. I started with a "clean slate" and deleted all database tables in my test database, and deleted all Data\Migrations.
2. Rebuilt the solution. (The base project and a unit testing project)
3. In Package Manager Console, ran "`Add-Migration StartupConfig`"
4. A migration file is added to Data\Migrations called "`{datetime}_StartupConfig.cs`". See `StartupConfig` class above.
5. I built the project.
6. I ran "`Update-Database -TargetMigration:StartupConfig`"
7. The PM console outputs 4 lines, including the "Running Seed method", and completes successfully.
8. I confirmed via SQL query that the "`__MigrationHistory`" and "`Families`" table have been added to the database, and each table has 1 record.
9. I ran the unit test and receive the error.

I had a more complex model, but I began removing things one by one making things as simple as I could. But I can't get any simpler than this, and yet the error persists. Of note, for this particular project I have never gotten a successful query out of the unit test.

As I was typing out these recreation steps above, I was performing the steps at the same time, and got the same error.

I am at a loss as to what to try next?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the context that has the connection string.  Verify that the unit test is passing in a connection to the same instance name and database name.  The unit test won't automatically use your web.config from the main startup project.

Comment: @AaronLS That's weird.. the connection string in the Watch window for ctx.Database.Connection is `"Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=testSQLConnection;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"`

Comment: That's not even a connection string that is in my application anywhere.. where is it getting that from ??? The migration is handling the connection fine. But when the unit test instantiates the context, it's getting this weird connection string. Any thoughts on what might be causing that?

Comment: Oh man.... the app.config for the Unit Test does not have the connection string... I bet it thinks the name is the database name since it can't resolve the connection string... wow.. Ok, I will test this...

Comment: Et voila. That was it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In checking the connection string in the Unit Test per @AaronLS suggestion, I found that the connection string was different.

Turns out, the App.config for the Unit Test did not have the connection string and was treating "sqlTestConnection" as the database name since it could not resolve it otherwise.

Adding the connection string to the App.config resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since you'r code it's not changing it has to be something with the Migrations table (the one that has info of your db model) or with the DB file you're using.

I will suggest to install Sql server express and try everything again. Since the database you're making is a file you will have more risk with it.

Edit:

Try to see the name of the instances your projects are using. By default EF use DefaultConnection. Check the web.config or configuration files in all your projects.

Comment: Take a look at the comments above. Somehow the connection string is getting changed. That would totally make sense as to why EF thinks the model has changes. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @jwatts1980 it has to be something with the configuration files of the project then. They're not pointing at the same place.